# redux hooks for functional component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I tried to convert redx into redux hooks.
- so I researched and found this link
  https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-redux-210bab340672
- I was able to make few changes.
- but not able to proceed further.
- It would be great if you guys let me know for one component.
- I can do it for others.
  -If you uncomment Button export you can see working code without hooks
- providing my code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wu-btlre

```
function useHackerNews(props) {
  const hackerNews = useSelector(state.channel);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        getPosts(channel);
        getAlert();
      }}
      className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
    >
      Get top news
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useSelector` takes a function with the state of redux store as a parameter, use the state of the store to return the desired data

```
const hackerNews = useSelector(state => state.channel);
```

Here's the updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-faraday-9eyk5

Comment: hey can you update in the sandbox, its so confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

basically you convert ´mapStateToProps´ using ´useSelector´

So this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ channel: state.channel });
```

Becomes:

```
const channel = useSelector(state => state.channel);
```

Your ´mapDispatchToProps´ is converted using ´useDispatch´

So you can convert:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { getPosts: fetchPosts, getAlert: displayAlert };
```

To:

```
const getPosts = () => useDispatch(fetchPosts());
const getAlert = () => useDispatch(displayAlert());
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: hey can you update in the sandbox, its so confusing :(